# Console.Write in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-mac

I start to learn .Net Core. I want to write a simple 'Hello World' console application.

Unfortunately the `System.Console` is not available initially. This is my code:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from Mac");        
    }
}
```

What package should I install?

FYI, I'm using Mac with VSCode and .net core rc1 update 2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure in your project.json system.console is referenced under 
`frameworks:dnxcore50:dependencies`

Example project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "ConsoleApp1 Console Application",
  "authors": [ "danny" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "compilationOptions": {
       "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
  },

  "commands": {
    "ConsoleApp1": "ConsoleApp1"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep. That worked. Could you please provide the a sample `project.son` file content for future reference.

Answer (score 80):

Also, just to save someone else the minor headache: Don't make the mistake of naming your project "MyThing.Console" like I did, or the `Console` reference in your code won't be referencing `System.Console`, it will be referencing your namespace looking for a **type** called `WriteLine`!

Comment: Oh dear... what should I say?

Comment: I can't believe this is what I did and didn't even notice. Sigh. Thank you.

Comment: What does it say about me that when I went to upvote this answer, I discovered that I had already upvoted it last year?

Comment: Thank you, this was driving me crazy.  This was exactly my issue.  Renaming the project without the `.Console` suffix fixed my problems.

Answer (score 14):

Just add NuGet Package

> System.Console

to your project. No need to muss around with project.json. That way, you also get the latest (stable) version.

One gotcha: if you name your console project Something.Console, be sure to fully qualify the path to Write, i.e.

> System.Console.Write();